# Load .mobileconfig to iPhone from Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, usb, mount, iphone

I'm trying to use Ubuntu 12.04 LTS to create and load *.mobileconfig files (normally created with iPhone Configuration Utility) onto an iOS devices via USB cable. I am having 2 problems.

1. I can't seem to mount the iPhone (iOS 7.1.2). **This is not the "Trust" bug; my iPhone doesn't even display the trust question to begin with.** I assume this means the iPhone is not communicating with the server. I have installed "libimobiledevice2", "libimobiledevice-utils", and "ideviceinstaller", but can't seem to get them working. I would prefer a solution that allows me to manually mount and unmount the iOS device, but just getting it to to work would be great at this point. I have checked that the USB cable works by syncing the iPhone with a Windows PC.
2. I haven't been able to find a tutorial or information on how to load the *.mobileconfig file onto the iPhone. So if anyone could point me to a tutorial, or explain the best way to accomplish this I would greatly appreciate it.

Please forgive me, but I'm a n00b. So I'll need very basic "step-by-step" style directions here.